# Error while Printing a Label with label.new in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to print a dynamic Label on my chart depending on the price behavior. Basically I am trying to plot the total cumulative volume of that wave on chart when the direction changes. Below is the part code snippet where I try to use the label.new() function through if condition

```
    if directionHasChanged or barstate.islast and not barstate.isrealtime or barstate.isrealtime and not barstate.isconfirmed
    plotChar := true

if directionIsDown and plotChar
    label.new(bar_index,high,style=label.style_none,text=volString,color=color.white)
```

But I am getting script error that reads - "**The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects.**"

What could be the reason and what is the possible solution or workaround to achieve the same. Below is the entire code of my script. Any help is appreciated. I am almost stuck for couple of days now

```
//@version=4
study("Weis Wave Chart", shorttitle="Weis", overlay=true, resolution="")
lblOffset = input(5, title="Label Offset")
method = input(defval="ATR", options=["ATR", "Traditional", "Part of Price"], title="Renko Assignment Method")
methodvalue = input(defval=14.0, type=input.float, minval=0, title="Value")
pricesource = input(defval="Close", options=["Close", "High / Low", "Open / Close"], title="Price Source")
useClose = pricesource == "Close"
useOpenClose = pricesource == "Open / Close" or useClose
useTrueRange = input(defval="Auto", options=["Always", "Auto", "Never"], title="Use True Range instead of Volume")
isOscillating = input(defval=false, type=input.bool, title="Oscillating")
normalize = input(defval=false, type=input.bool, title="Normalize")
vol = useTrueRange == "Always" or useTrueRange == "Auto" and na(volume) ? tr : volume
op = useClose ? close : open
hi = useOpenClose ? close >= op ? close : op : high
lo = useOpenClose ? close <= op ? close : op : low

if method == "ATR"
    methodvalue := atr(round(methodvalue))
if method == "Part of Price"
    methodvalue := close / methodvalue

currclose = float(na)
prevclose = nz(currclose[1])
prevhigh = prevclose + methodvalue
prevlow = prevclose - methodvalue
currclose := hi > prevhigh ? hi : lo < prevlow ? lo : prevclose

direction = int(na)
direction := currclose > prevclose ? 1 : currclose < prevclose ? -1 : nz(direction[1])
directionHasChanged = change(direction) != 0
directionIsUp = direction > 0
directionIsDown = direction < 0

extr = float(na)
fixnan_1 = fixnan(extr[1])
prevextr = directionHasChanged ? currclose : fixnan_1
extr := directionIsUp and hi >= prevextr ? hi : directionIsDown and lo <= prevextr ? lo : prevextr
   
barcount = 1
barcount := not directionHasChanged and normalize ? barcount[1] + barcount : barcount
vol := not directionHasChanged ? vol[1] + vol : vol
res = barcount > 1 ? vol / barcount : vol
volString = tostring(res)

f_calc_bar_time(offset) => ret = time + ((time-time[1]) * offset)
//var label = label.new(bar_index, na)

//label.set_text(label, "green")
//label.set_size(label, "10")
//label.set_textcolor(label, color.white)
//label.set_yloc(label, yloc.belowbar)
//label.set_style(label, label.style_none)
mLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, '5m', low[1], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off,  lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
mHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, '5m', high[1], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off,  lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)


//f_print_low(_txt) => var _lbl = label(na), label.delete(_lbl), _lbl := label.new(time + (time-time[1]) * 5, low, style=label.style_none,text=_txt,color=color.white)
//f_print_high(_txt) => var _lbl = label(na), label.delete(_lbl), _lbl := label.new(bar_index[0], high, style=label.style_none,text=_txt,color=color.white)


//if directionHasChanged
//if directionIsUp
    //label.new(f_calc_bar_time(lblOffset), mLow, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text=tostring(res), style=label.style_none, color=color.white)
      
//if directionIsDown
    //label.new(f_calc_bar_time(lblOffset), mHigh, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text=tostring(res), style=label.style_none, color=color.white)
var plotChar = false
var up = false
var down = false
var upLbl = 0
var dwnLbl = 0
if directionHasChanged or barstate.islast and not barstate.isrealtime or barstate.isrealtime and not barstate.isconfirmed
    plotChar := true

if directionIsDown and plotChar
    label.new(bar_index,high,style=label.style_none,text=volString,color=color.white)
if directionIsUp and plotChar
    down := true
    dwnLbl := 1

//plotchar(series=plotChar, color=color.white,char='3')
plotchar(series=up,color=color.white,location=location.abovebar, text="3")
plotchar(series=down,color=color.white,location=location.belowbar, text="3")

//label.new(upLbl,high,style=label.style_none,text=volString,color=color.white)
//label.new(dwnLbl,low,style=label.style_none,text=volString,color=color.white)

plotChar := false
up := false
down := false
upLbl := 0
dwnLbl := 0
plot(directionHasChanged or barstate.islast and not barstate.isrealtime or barstate.isrealtime and not barstate.isconfirmed ? extr[1] : na, offset=-1, color=#1155CC, transp=50, linewidth=2, title="Wave Line")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `resolution=""` parameter in your `study()` declaration.

```
study("Weis Wave Chart", shorttitle="Weis", overlay=true, resolution="")
```

When you remove it, the script compiles without errors.
You have to change it to this:

```
study("Weis Wave Chart", shorttitle="Weis", overlay=true)
```